# Remove currency symbol from column SSDBGrid

Tags: vb6, grid

I have an `SSDBGrid` with a column that is displaying values in a table with a data type of Currency. Therefore, this column shows values with a £ symbol in front of them - e.g. £10, rather than 10.

I've had a look at the properties of the columns, but I can't work out which one will allow me to remove the currency symbol?

I've tried

```
With grdList
   .Columns(2).CellStyleSet = "0.##"
End With
```

But that made no difference. I can't see any other properties that would allow me do this? How can it be done?

Comment: I don't have an SSDBGrid to look at but a quick google search turned up some suggestions to set the column NumberFormat property.